# What is the best practice to send data from wordpress to 3rd party API

Tags: json, wordpress, fetch

I need to send data from wordpress site to 3rd party API and want to know how to do it in the best and correct way. As i understand i could do it with php function or with javascript. What is better and correct way? Is it also any in-built wordpress functions for this?

Comment: does that site where you want  to send the data to, provide api to interact with that site ?

Comment: Yeah. I mean both site would be mine so main server, which would get data i could organize how i need. If to be more correct, wordpress sites would be few, and all them would send data to one main server

Comment: Is receiver server's site in wordpress?

Comment: @MithuAQuayium No. It is Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data to site A (Server's site) from site B, these both sites need to communicate. And the way of communication is api. Since site A is to receive data and site B is to send data, so the api would have to be available from site A and site B will use that api to send the data to site A. This is the concept.

Now what is api: Nowaday api generally refers to REST API, since it is now common trend. it is something that provides you url, through which you get or send data in json format with post or get method. More about this topic can be found here in details: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/

Since site A is in ruby on rails, you can make api for that following the steps like this link: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one.

After making api in site A, you may have any url for sending data. Let's say the url is {site_name}/send_data and this url uses post method to receive data from any site (in this case, from site B)

Now, since site B uses wp, this already has builtin function wp_remote_post, which uses the api url and the data as parameter to send the data to that url. This way you will be able to send the data to site A.

```
wp_remote_post( '{site_name}/send_data', $data_to_send_as_array )
```

More about wp_remote_post: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/

Comment: Yeah, perhaps function that you suggest is what i'm looking for. My problem was not how to organize process on both servers, but only what is the best way to send data from wordpress. Looks that this wp_remore_post() function is the best way in this case. Thank you!